# Get position-X from distance traveled within boundaries

Tags: python

I have two blue points moving in opposite directions. I'm given the size limit on the X-Axis in which the points can move. In this example it's 300 units total (150 in either direction from 0)

Each blue point starts at 0 (the center) and I'm given the total distance at which each point has moved. I'm having trouble writing a function which returns me their resulting X position. Which is indicated by a light blue dot in the image below. The red line indicates the boundaries which ball can move within, think of the red lines as walls and the blue points as bouncing balls.

My goal is to make a function which returns me this value in python.

[image]

You'll see in my function that I have an argument dir which is meant to be used to determine which direction the ball is moving (left or right initially)

Below is my attempt at solving it, but it's not entirely correct. It seems to fail when there are remainders from the %.

```
def find_position(dir=1, width=10, traveled=100):
    dist = traveled
    x = dist % (width*0.5)
    print x

find_position(dir=1, width=300, traveled=567)
find_position(dir=1, width=300, traveled=5)
find_position(dir=-1, width=300, traveled=5)
find_position(dir=-1, width=300, traveled=325)


>> output
117.0
5.0
5.0
25.0

>> should be
-33.0
5.0
-5.0
25.0
```

Comment: If the top dot moved 567 units to the right, how is it then at -33?

Comment: Once the point hits the bounds of he container it then moves back towards the other direction. ill add that bit to the question

Comment: Ahh, that makes more sense.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's a critical part :) i just forgot about it. Thanks for seeing that

Comment: Np. You should show the output that you are getting too. Showing the bad output is usually a good addition to the question. Not everyone can easily run the code on the fly.

Comment: ok ill add that now

Comment: The first given answer appears to be wrong. I just did the first ball manually on some paper, and I got 117 as well.

Comment: And for the other ones, you're never using `dir`! It seems like you could just multiply the result by `dir` to get the right answer, but test that first to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `%` and an absolute value:

**Code:**

```
def find_position(direction=1, width=10, traveled=100):
    half_width = width / 2
    t = abs((traveled + half_width) % (2 * width) - width) - half_width
    return -t * direction
```

**Test Code:**

```
assert int(find_position(direction=1, width=300, traveled=567)) == -33.0
assert int(find_position(direction=1, width=300, traveled=5)) == 5
assert int(find_position(direction=-1, width=300, traveled=5)) == -5
assert int(find_position(direction=-1, width=300, traveled=325)) == 25
```

Comment: how could this be modified to allow for the blue point's starting position to be anywhere with the red boundaries? Rather than always assuming it's the center at 0

Comment: Try `traveled += start * direction` as the first line of the function

Answer (score 1):

The following will do, the sign of m indicates the direction (you can easily make it more generic, by making 150 and 300 parameters):

```
def x(m):
    d = 150 + m
    # what matters the most is whether it bounced even times or odd times
    return (1 if d // 300 % 2 == 0 else -1) * (d % 300 - 150)    

assert x(567) == -33
assert x(-325) == 25

assert x(-100) == -100
assert x(-150) == -150
assert x(-160) == -140
assert x(-300) == 0
assert x(-310) == 10
assert x(-450) == 150 
assert x(-460) == 140

assert x(100) == 100
assert x(150) == 150
assert x(160) == 140
assert x(300) == 0
assert x(310) == -10 
assert x(450) == -150
assert x(460) == -140
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my code for your problem. I've left comment in the code to make it more self explanatory. But shouldn't you expect the coordinate of X would be -25 when it traveled -325 starting from 0?

```
def find_position(dir=1, width=10, traveled=100):
    # coordinate translation
    curr_X = 150

    if traveled >= width:
        # remove periodicity in distance traveled
        dist = traveled % width * dir
    else:
        dist = traveled * dir

    new_X = ( dist + curr_X ) % width

    # translate coordinate back to original configuration
    new_X = new_X - width * 0.5
    return new_X

assert find_position(dir=1, width=300, traveled=567) == -33
assert find_position(dir=1, width=300, traveled=5) == 5
assert find_position(dir=-1, width=300, traveled=5) == -5
assert find_position(dir=-1, width=300, traveled=325) == -25
```

Comment: Your solution is so close. X should be +25 since it's the X position. Think of it as a grid. The final resting position would be positive 25. How can we correct that?

Comment: Exactly, that is why you should get -25 if you travel 325 in the direction of -1.

Comment: you are correct in the sense that it's -25 units from it's original start position. But if you were to plot the points onto a grid it would be 0 and the resulting end point would be 25

Comment: wait nevermind the last comment, i think your solution may work for what i need. ill test it out now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_position(dir=1, width=10, traveled=100):
    # If we have traveled less than half the width, just return 
    # the traveled distance
    if traveled < (width / 2):
        return traveled * dir

    dist = traveled % width

    # If the remainder is less than half the board, we know we are not 
    # "halfway" around the board, so we can just return the distance again
    if dist <= (width / 2):
        return dist * dir

    # Here we have wrapped around the final round, so we subtract the width 
    # of the board to get the final distance
    return (width - dist) * dir * -1
```

Output:

```
>>> find_position(dir=1, width=300, traveled=567)
-33
>>> find_position(dir=1, width=300, traveled=5)
5
>>> find_position(dir=-1, width=300, traveled=5)
-5
>>> find_position(dir=-1, width=300, traveled=325)
-25
```